# I have the following view working on Django. Can I do the same with a Generic View?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, inline-formset

I have the following view working on Django. Can I do the same with a Generic View?

#
models :

RiskAssessment
 # contains name and information

RiskLine
 # contains many lines per (RiskAssessment ForeignKKey)
#

```
def risk_view(request, pk=None):

    if  pk == None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/riskassessment/') # No pk show list
    else:
        risk = RiskAssessment.objects.get(id = pk)

    RiskLineSet    = inlineformset_factory(RiskAssessment, RiskLine, can_delete=False, exclude=('user',))    

    if request.method == "POST":
        riskform      = RiskForm(request.POST, instance=risk)
        risklineset   = RiskLineSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=risk)

        if riskform.is_valid() and risklineset.is_valid():
            riskform.save()
            risklineset.save()

            # Redirect to somewhere
            if '_save' in request.POST:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/riskassessmentlist/')
            if '_addanother' in request.POST:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/riskassessmentnew/')

    else:
        riskform      = RiskForm(instance=risk)
        risklineset   = RiskLineSet(instance=risk)

    return render_to_response('formulare/RiskAssessment/risk.html', {
        'riskform'    : riskform,
        'risklineset'  : risklineset,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

Comment: Short answer: yes. For longer answer please ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class RiskView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'formulare/RiskAssessment/risk.html'
    risk = None
    RiskLineSet = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk', None) is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/riskassessment/')  # No pk show list
        else:
            self.risk = RiskAssessment.objects.get(id=pk)

        self.RiskLineSet = inlineformset_factory(RiskAssessment, RiskLine, can_delete=False, exclude=('user',))
        return super(RiskView, self).dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RiskView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['riskform'] = RiskForm(instance=self.risk)
        context['risklineset'] = self.RiskLineSet(instance=self.risk)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        riskform = RiskForm(request.POST, instance=self.risk)
        risklineset = self.RiskLineSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=self.risk)

        if riskform.is_valid() and risklineset.is_valid():
            riskform.save()
            risklineset.save()

            # Redirect to somewhere
            if '_save' in request.POST:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/riskassessmentlist/')
            if '_addanother' in request.POST:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/riskassessmentnew/')
            # Otherwise, I guess you want to redirect to the same view
            return HttpResponseRedirect('url_of_the_current_view')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a working function based view, you don't have to switch to a class based view.

None of the built in generic views are designed for formsets. If you used a Django Class based view, you would have to do quite a lot of customizing.

One option would be to use the [`InlineFormsetView`](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html#inlineformsetview) from django-extra-views.